# define a custom css class that uses bootstrap classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

All,

Is there any way to define a custom CSS class that uses existing bootstrap classes?

For example, consider the following HTML snippet:

`<div class="text-primary center-block">Here is some text</div>`

Bootstrap will automatically make it blue and centered and displayed block.  But adding all of those classes is a lot to remember.  Can I just use my own class:

`<div class="my_class">Here is some text</div>`

And somehow in a CSS file add those Bootstrap properties?

The only solution I can think of is using JQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(
  function() {
    $(".my_class").each(function() {
      $(this).addClass("text-primary center-block");      
    });
  }
);
```

But is there a better solution?

Comment: No, you cannot extend a CSS class.

Comment: your jQuery code could be simplified to ````$(".my_class").addClass("text-primary center-block")````

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hi yes there is a better way, if you are using the Less Source version of Bootstrap you can setup Bootstrap's Classes as Less Mixins by importing the Less files as a Reference

Which would mean you could setup something like this:

```
 .custom-class { .text-primary; center-block; }
```

This post discusses the technique in detail:

http://transmission.vehikl.com/using-bootstrap-as-a-semantic-mixin-library/

Comment: This sounds very promising.  I will look into it and get back to you.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following: but this is work with [SCSS](https://www.w3schools.com/sass/sass_extend.php#:%7E:text=The%20%40extend%20directive%20lets%20you,differ%20in%20some%20small%20details.) not with the standard CSS

```
.my_class
{
    @extend .text-primary; 
    @extend .center-block;
}
```

Hope it helps!